# How to Simplify/remesh mesh

Tags: mesh, remesh

how can I simplify this mesh?

[image: 1]

(I have to reduce the amount of internal edges, without altering the form of the total mesh)

Comment: You could try Limited Dissolve. - In Edit mode. select All then use the Mesh > Clean Up > Limited Dissolve menu.

Comment: ..or after selecting all with `A` hit `X` > _Limited Dissolve_ if you want to do it with shortcuts in the viewport. I would use `A`for the selection because with a mesh like this and in the current view mode (_Solid_ with no _X-Ray_ enabled or perhaps _Wireframe_ mode instead), if you just box select the mesh there might be overlapping areas which do not get selected if the are lying in the background.

Comment: Limites dissolve worked perfectly, tanks!